# Best way to to select between 100 situations on a game map(MFC,CPoint)

Tags: c++, object, if-statement, mfc, switch-statement

I am creating an MFC old times game(something like Dungeons and Dragons), I'm representing the location of my character as a CPoint object.
the map is between(0,0) to (9,9) , 10 x 10.
each point should has its own different story.
What way is the best to choose each time between each point and what happend?

I thought about few options:

A. I will check each time that a player click on a move button(for exampl he choose to move East), and do many ifs t check what should happend in that location .

example:

```
void CProjectDlg::OnBnClickedWest()
{
    (*Location).x--;
    if(Location->x ==0)
        CWest.EnableWindow(false);
    if(Location->x <9)
        CEast.EnableWindow(true);

    if(Location->x==0 && Location->y==0)
        do something;
    else
        if(Location->x==1 && Location->y==0)
           do something else...;
    etc...;
}
```

B. I will do the same but with a switch on all locations(if possible).
example:

```
void CProjectDlg::OnBnClickedWest()
{
    (*Location).x--;
    if(Location->x ==0)
        CWest.EnableWindow(false);
    if(Location->x <9)
        CEast.EnableWindow(true);

    switch(Location)
       case ((0,0)):
         something;
}
```

Please help me

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would say, use the one that makes you feel more comfortable.

Comment: A common solution to reduce the complexity of `if`-cascades or huge `switch` statements is to use a look-up table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the answer was to use switch based ( which was the best for choosing between 100 options.. thanks everyone!